# Route [backpack.auth.login] not defined

Tags: laravel-backpack

Im getting the above error when trying to load any page in my laravel app.

When it runs on my local machine it works find but i have been trying to move this into production and it throwing this error.

Any ideas?

works fine on my local dev environment but not on staging server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is it possible that you have different configurations on production vs dev ? Something like `setup_auth_routes` in `config/backpack/base.php` or similar configurations that could raise that error?

Also is worth to check if you have your routes cached in production and the backpack routes have no effect.

You can re-build the route caching with `php artisan route:cache`, or `php artisan route:clear` to simply clear the cache.

Same applies for configs, you can also try `php artisan config:cache` to rebuild the cache, or `php artisan config:clear` to just clear configuration caches.

If nothing that helps, can you do a `php artisan route:list` ? Also a `php artisan backpack:version` could help debug any further issues.

Also please post a more complete error trace (you can find it in `storage/logs/laravel.log`.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for the help.

I actually worked this out to be related to the settings in the backpack guard settings.

 I had originally used laravel/ui for login ect then switched over to backpack auth but it looks like some vendor files where still present in dev which did not come back down in prod which is why it didnt work.

After changing backpack guard back to defaults it seems to have fixed the issue.